# Is there a delta transform for collection?

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms, keyframes, 3d-manipulator

[image]

I made this guy here, he is made of 29 individual objects, I want to draw over it with grease pencil, but I cant rotate him with the rest of the frames. Its nice that I can use the delta transform to change the puppet size to make a variety of siluets without animate them once more but that's useless if I cant move them around.

Answer (score 1):

Collections are not objects with a presence in the 3D space. A better solution would have been to parent all these objects to another object, such as an empty object.

1. create the empty object with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Empty > Plain Axes
2. Select all your meshes, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> the empty and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Set Parent

You probably also want to make sure that empty is in the same collection by selecting it and pressing <kbd>M</kbd> to move it in the right collection.

Comment: Works marvelously. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> your collection in the outliner, *Select Objects*.
Now you can move, rotate, scale, etc. all the objects together.

Or:

If all the objects you want to move together are the only ones visible, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and move, rotate, scale, etc.

Comment: and Im supposed to do that for the rest of the 40 frames?